# JAXB element of type enum

Tags: enums, types, schema, jaxb, element

So I know how to create an enum type but when I set an element type to it the element field will just be of type string and not of type enum. How do I create an enum in my schema and have JAXB generate it as a java enum type?

This is how I'm doing my enum type and element creation:

```xml
<xsd:simpleType name="myEnum">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="MY_ENUM_1"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="MY_ENUM_2"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:element name="myEnumElement" type="ns1:myEnum"/>
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You could form your XML schema as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.example.com" xmlns="http://www.example.com" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:simpleType name="myEnum">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="MY_ENUM_1"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="MY_ENUM_2"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:element name="root">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="local" type="myEnum"/>
                <xsd:element name="ref" type="myEnum"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Will cause the following Enum to be generated:

```java
package com.example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlType(name = "myEnum")
@XmlEnum
public enum MyEnum {

    MY_ENUM_1,
    MY_ENUM_2;

    public String value() {
        return name();
    }

    public static MyEnum fromValue(String v) {
        return valueOf(v);
    }

}
```

And the following class that leverages that Enum:

```java
package com.example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "local",
    "ref"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
public class Root {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected MyEnum local;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected MyEnum ref;

    public MyEnum getLocal() {
        return local;
    }

    public void setLocal(MyEnum value) {
        this.local = value;
    }

    public MyEnum getRef() {
        return ref;
    }

    public void setRef(MyEnum value) {
        this.ref = value;
    }

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/jaxb-and-enums.html

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan If i am returning a numeric(ordinal) from my enum Changing "<xsd:enumeration value="MY_ENUM_1/>" to "value="0" is enough ??

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar - This post will show how to handle numeric enum values:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/jaxb-and-enums.html

Comment: whats the point of fromValue ? Its just does the same as valueOf()

Comment: @NimChimpsky - fromValue would be generated code from the JAX-B compiler, conforming to the getter/setter naming conventions

Answer (score 3):

See `jaxb:globalBindings/@typeSafeEnumBase` [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html).